# android bluetooth multiple connections

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I would like to build a Group Chat using Android Bluetooth. Now I'm trying to send message from one device to multiple devices and receiving messages from multiple devices.

My approach is to first create a BluetoothServerSocket:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(mBluetoothAdapter.getName(), uuid);
```

And client will try to connect using this uuid. Once connected, I'll do:

```
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("1");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception 1");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("2");

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
                connectedThread.start();

                // Notify that this uuid is used
                mHandler.obtainMessage(SOCKET_ACCEPTED, serverUUID).sendToTarget();
            }
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Basically I get the socket from a client and pass to another thread for communication. Then I close the server socket and recreate one. In handler I'll re run this thread again and listing to another client.

For client I just do a normal connection and have a `HashMap` to maintain `<Device, Thread>` relation.

I tested this mechanism on three devices, and they can send message to other two and receive message from other two devices.

Here are my questions:

1. From what I heard, some people said to have multiple connection I need to use different UUIDs, but my mechanisms only need one and works. Can somebody explain this?
2. Since I'm only using one UUID, but the Bluetooth spec only allow 7 devices connected at the same time. So if one device is connected to 7 devices and there is another one trying to connect, what will happen? (I don't have that many devices on hand so can't test it)
3. Any potential problems for my solution?

Comment: I use one UUID for multiple connections also. I have done some experiment and found that different devices have different max number of connection. And the whole network will become very unstable if too many connections. I am also looking for a solution.